# Are long jQuery chains bad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, plugins

I've been using jQuery a long time and I've been writing a slideshow plugin for my work and I (not 100% consciously) wrote probably 75% it in a single chain. It's fully commented and i specify each `end()` and what it's resetting it to, etc, but does this *slow down* jQuery or the DOM loading, or, does this actually speed it up?

Comment: tagged this `[performance]` as well, since that's the main concern it seems :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on your specific code, as always.  As for storing a reference vs [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/), well...with a really long chain, it's faster *not to chain* vs [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) calls, simply because you have to handle the extra baggage (storing/restoring), like the `.prevObject` reference, the [`.selector`](http://api.jquery.com/selector/), [`.context`](http://api.jquery.com/context/), etc that you *probably* don't care about in many cases....and just more intertwined references to previous objects.

Where it's more costly is harder to measure...it's not the execution (though that is slower, even if infinitesimally)...it's the more complicated garbage collection to clean up all those objects later, since the dependency graph is now much larger.

Now...will it make a *measurable* difference? not unless your chain is really long, in which case it's *probably* a micro-optimization you need not worry about in most cases.

99% of the time, unless you're making some egregious performance penalizing call, *don't worry about it*, as with most micro-optimizations.  If you're having a problem with performance, then get into it.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. I do caching, etc, but for this there aren't that many selectors and the code just kinda flowed well being chained, so i went with it then i thought... uh oh... this might slow things down.

Answer (score 6):

One of the most expensive things you can do in a modern browser is to access and manipulate the DOM. Chaining lets you minimize the actual lookups that you have to do, which can mean significantly faster code. The other option is to do the initial lookup, store that in a variable, and do everything off of that variable. That being said, jquery was specifically designed with that chaining api in mind, so it is more idiomatic to chain.

Answer (score 4):

I think chainability of jQuery is a great feature ... one should really use it more often.
for example:

```
$(this)
  .find('.funky')
  .css('width', 30)
  .attr('title', 'Funky Title')
.end()
.fadeIn();
```

is much better (and elegant) - don't have to create 2 jQuery `$(this)` objects than :

```
$(this).find('.funky').css('width', 30).attr('title', 'Funky Title');
$(this).fadeIn();
```

Comment: You don't have to create two jQuery `$(this)`... `var obj = $(this).find('.funky').css('width', 30).attr('title', 'Funky Title'); obj.fadeIn();`

Comment: of course if You store it in a variable - but that's not what most jQuery users tend to write in my experience, they just "abuse" $().
that is why I do found the chainability elegant - one can stay cheap on variables :). besides You're code does smt different than mine ... (fading `$(this).find('.funky')` instead of `$(this)`)

Comment: @Matt - that won't have the same effect, your `obj` variable refers to some `.find` elements, not `this` :)

Comment: @kares and @Nick: In my haste, I variablized (cool word there!) the wrong part... `var obj = $(this).find('.funky');` is what I meant :).

Comment: @Matt so how do You fade `this` DOM element with this variabilization ... ?

Comment: @kares: Jesus, don't know what's up with me. I blame haste on the first comment, and tiredness on the second :P. I'll get there eventually: `var obj = $(this); obj.find('.funky').css('width', 30).attr('title', 'Funky Title'); obj.fadeIn();`. If that's still not right, I give up :P

Answer (score 2):

My *guess* would be no difference, or faster, due to lack of intermediaries.

The only major drawback is to clarity, if you think via comments that it is obvious without making it multi-line with intermediate variables, via virtue of comments or just a nicely clean call chain then fine.